# Get information whether text is extractable from PDF

Tags: pdf, encoding, fonts, text-extraction

I have a lot of PDF files. In some of them, I can easily copy/paste text from PDF to any text editor. In others, copy/paste produces garbage only (strange, unreadable characters). As I understand it now, this is because of embedded fonts and/or custom encoding (but maybe I'm wrong).

I've chosen 10 PDFs and used `pdffonts` to extract fonts related information. From PDFs starting with c  (correct) text can be copied, from those beginning with w (wrong) text cannot be copied. Output of `pdffonts` command is below.

Is it true that I can identify wrong documents by presence of custom ecoding? In other words, if there is custom encoding, you cannot copy/paste text from PDF?

```
./comparison/c1.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
DDDWSC+MyriadPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      9  
DDDWSC+MyriadPro-Bold                CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     18  
XPQSAJ+MinionPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     36  
QQNHBI+MyriadPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    121  
MyriadPro-Regular                    Type 1C (OT)      WinAnsi          yes no  no      82  
./comparison/c2.pdf

name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object I
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
GBITER+MyriadPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      9  
GBITER+MyriadPro-Bold                CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     18  
TPIJNO+MinionPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     36  
HCPLUP+MyriadPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     99  
CFAHCZ+MyriadPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    100  
MyriadPro-Regular                    Type 1C (OT)      WinAnsi          yes no  no      82  

./comparison/c3.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object 
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- --------
FTWOKY+MyriadPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      8  
FTWOKY+MyriadPro-Bold                CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      9  
HDAKMN+MinionPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     34  
CYRRXP+MyriadPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    119  
MyriadPro-Regular                    Type 1C (OT)      WinAnsi          yes no  no      80  

./comparison/c4.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- --------
TimesNewRoman                        CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes      8  
TimesNewRoman,Bold                   CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes      9  
TimesNewRoman,BoldItalic             CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes     30  
TimesNewRomanPSMT                    TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      10  
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT               TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      31  
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT         TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      32  
Arial-BoldItalicMT                   TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      33  
CPWIYN+MinionPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     56  
PZAZAE+MyriadPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    120  
MyriadPro-Regular                    Type 1C (OT)      WinAnsi          yes no  no     102  

./comparison/c5.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object 
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- -------
TimesNewRoman                        CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes      9  
TimesNewRoman,Bold                   CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes     10  
TimesNewRomanPSMT                    TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      11  
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT               TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      12  
PKLOUG+MinionPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     43  
ZWNFNP+MyriadPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    120  
MyriadPro-Regular                    Type 1C (OT)      WinAnsi          yes no  no      89  

./comparison/w1.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object 
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- --------
ECCDLD+TimesNewRomanPSMT             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       5  
ECCDMD+TimesNewRoman                 Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       6  
ECCDNE+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       7  
ECCDNF+TimesNewRoman,Bold            Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       8  
MinionPro-Regular-Identity-H         CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes no  no      24  

./comparison/w2.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object 
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- --------
DIKJDI+TimesNewRoman,Bold            Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       5  
DIKJEJ+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       6 0
DIKJEK+TimesNewRomanPSMT             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       7  
DIKJEL+TimesNewRoman                 Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       8  
MinionPro-Regular-Identity-H         CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes no  no      22  

./comparison/w3.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object 
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- --------
LLHACL+Calibri                       Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes      5  
LLHACM+Calibri-Bold                  Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes      6  
LLHBBI+Calibri-Italic                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     20  
MinionPro-Regular-Identity-H         CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes no  no      21  

./comparison/w4.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object 
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- --------EPGNDG+TimesNewRoman                 Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       5  
EPGNDH+TimesNewRomanPSMT             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       6  
EPGNDI+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       7  
EPGNGI+TimesNewRoman,Bold            Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       8  
MinionPro-Regular-Identity-H         CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes no  no      19  
OXKXLW+MyriadPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     60  
MyriadPro-Regular                    Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no      52  

./comparison/w5.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object 
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- --------
JPDEFN+TimesNewRoman                 Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       5  
JPDEHN+TimesNewRomanPSMT             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       6  
JPDEIN+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       7  
JPDEJO+TimesNewRoman,Bold            Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       8  MinionPro-Regular-Identity-H         CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes no  no      25
```

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question so I removed my initial answer. If you can copy/paste but end with with garbage chars, the problem is most likely related to the CMap that is either corrupt or unsupported. I can't recommend a tool that will allow you to check for a correct CMap but it might help you with further research.

Comment: *Is it true that I can identify wrong documents by presence of custom ecoding? In other words, if there is custom encoding, you cannot copy/paste text from PDF?* - No. Any custom encoding with a **correct** ToUnicode mapping in the font allows text extraction. And a seemingly standard encoding may be misleading: There are documents that e.g. tag their fonts as WinAnsi encoded but which actually  are not.